# how to prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)] = L \implies \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} [f(x)/x] = L$

Tags: limits, infinity

I don’t know how to formally prove that
if $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(f(x+1)-f(x)\right) = L,$$ then $$\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = L$$

where L is a constant and the function is limited whit in a limited domain.
I tryed to expand the definition of infinit limit but have no idea where to go on from there or even if that is the best aproach.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You should take a look at this [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to properly format your mathematical expressions for this site using MathJax. Also, you should edit your question to include what you have tried or what you understand or don't understand about the problem.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Can you update the question with definition of both limits?

Comment: To be honest i opend the definition of limit and thats it, i have no idea the right aproch. L just stands for the value is a constant.

Comment: This is false in general. Consider $f : x \mapsto \tan(\pi x)$. For such a $f$, you have $f(x+1)-f(x)=0$ for all $x$, but $f(x)/x$ does not tend to $0$. However, if $f$ is a continuous function, the result holds.